# binding std::normal_distribution to a std::function for storage in std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, std

I am trying to store several different types of c++ distributions into a single container and I thought I could use the std::function for this purpose. My attempt at doing this is as follows:

```
void print_rand(){
    // Make the random number generator
    std::random_device rd{};
    std::mt19937 engine(rd());

    // Store the distribution in a std::function
    auto n1 = std::make_shared<std::normal_distribution<double>>(0,1);
    std::function<double (std::mt19937)>  fn = std::bind(&std::normal_distribution<double>::operator(), n1, std::placeholders::_1);

    // Call the function to get a normally distributed number
    std::cerr << fn(engine) << std::endl;
}
```

but I get the following error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘bind(<unresolved overloaded function type>, std::shared_ptr<std::normal_distribution<double> >&, const std::_Placeholder<1>&)’
     std::function<double (std::mt19937)>  fn = std::bind(&std::normal_distribution<double>::operator(), n1, std::placeholders::_1);
```

When I tried template specializing the operator() call like:

```
std::function<double (std::mt19937)>  fn = std::bind(&std::normal_distribution<double>::operator()<std::mt19937>, n1, std::placeholders::_1);
```

I get the same error.

Any tips would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you put a `normal_distribution` into a `std::function`:

```
std::normal_distribution<double> nd(0, 1);
std::function<double(std::mt19937&)> fn = nd;
```

No `shared_ptr`, no `bind`, no lambda, no copying of random number engines (note the `&`).

Comment: Thanks this is much simpler! Changing the accepted answer to this. One question: does std::function make and hold onto a copy of the distribution?